# grep without showing path/file:line

Tags: linux, unix, grep, find

How do you grep and only return the matching line? i.e. The path/filename is omitted from the results.

In this case I want to look in all .bar files in the current directory, searching for the term FOO

```
find . -name '*.bar' -exec grep -Hn FOO {} \;
```

Answer (score 468, accepted):

No need to `find`. If you are just looking for a pattern within a specific directory, this should suffice:

```
grep -hn FOO /your/path/*.bar
```

Where `-h` is the parameter to hide the filename, as from `man grep`:

> **-h, --no-filename**
>
> Suppress  the  prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default
>   when  there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.

Note that you were using

> **-H, --with-filename**
>
> Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is
>   more than one file to search.

Comment: can line number be omitted?

Comment: @javadba you are probably using an alias, type `alias grep`. To omit the alias, type `\grep ...`

Comment: Yes it was using the alias.

Comment: @javadba omit the -n flag

Answer (score 8):

Just replace `-H` with `-h`. Check `man grep` for more details on options

```
find . -name '*.bar' -exec grep -hn FOO {} \;
```

Answer (score 7):

From the man page:

```
-h, --no-filename
    Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default when there
    is only one file (or only standard input) to search.
```