# grep command need out put without path to file

Tags: macos, unix, grep

When I am using following grep command to find specific word in bunch of folders and subfolders it shows me that line with path to that file.

```
grep -r "key_word = " ./
```

results

```
./folder1/sub1/file name/keyword line = 12
./folder1/sub1/sub12/file name/keyword line = 1.3
./.................                                   = 12                      
./                                  = 12
./                 = 12
etc.
```

Is there any way to get the out put keyword line without path to file name like below

```
key word = 12
key word = 1.3
key word = 12
key word = 12
```

Then it is easy to compare that line for my task
does any one have any idea how to do that?
I have thousands of files in those directories to read and grab that line.

Comment: Try adding `-h` switch `grep -h`

Comment: grep -hn keyword/your/path/*.* this only work for one folder @fedorqui

Comment: Just add `-h` to your current command: `grep -hr "key_word = " ./`. That's the key aspect I wanted to indicate from the duplicated question I linked.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [grep without showing path/file:line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406761/grep-without-showing-path-fileline), just add `-h` to your current command:

```
grep -hr "key_word = " ./
      ^
```