# Ubuntu grep that will show a word pattern and assign to variable

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I am trying to do a grep to print a text patern (usr1234) for a directory. 
The best I could do so far is save the filename and line were the word is found. 
usr1234 can have 3 digits or 4: usr123 or usr1234

This is my current grep:

```
usrcode=$(grep -oPnr 'usr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' filename)
```

and the result is:

```
filename/filelocation/file:7:usr1234 filename/filelocation2/file2:8:usr1234 filename/filelocation3/file3:7:usr1234
```

all I need is to store usr1234(or usr123 depending on the case)

Comment: so you don't want the name of the file to be printed? Have you tried with [grep -h](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19406829/1983854)?

Comment: grep -h prints nothing

Comment: grep -ohnr 'usr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' /customers/$1 is closer. it prints: 7:usr1234 7:usr1234 8:1234 8:usr1234 9:usr1234 9:usr1234

Comment: Just remove the `-n` that stands for line number.

Answer (score 1):

The lucky one:

```
usrcode=$(grep -ohr 'usr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' filename  | head -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it do sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(usr[0-9]*\)/\2/'
```

Like this:

```
usrcode=$(grep -oPnr 'usr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' filename | sed 's/\(.*\)\(usr[0-9]*\)/\2/')
```

Comment: Close but it prints usr1234 usr1234 usr1234 usr1234 usr1234

Comment: It works for me with Your example.
You can always cut it to first phrase with awk:
    awk '{print $1}'
like:
    usrcode=$(grep -oPnr 'usr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' filename | sed 's/\(.*\)\(usr[0-9]*\)/\2/') | awk '{print $1}'